# SSRS reference report variable from report function

Tags: function, reporting-services, reference

In SSRS, is it possible to reference a report variable from a report function?

Below is my report function. Instead of declaring and setting the MaxRFWIDRange in the function, I'd rather reference a report variable with the same name.

```
Function ValidateRFWIDRange(FromRFW As Integer, ToRFW As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim DiffRFW As Integer
    Dim MaxRFWIDRange As Integer
    MaxRFWIDRange = 10000
    DiffRFW = ToRFW - FromRFW

    If DiffRFW > MaxRFWIDRange Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End if
End Function
```

Comment: Could you pass the value into your function during an expression evaluation?

Comment: I'm calling it from a hidden parameter like this: =Code.ValidateRFWIDRange(Parameters!FromRFW.Value, Parameters!ToRFW.Value) and I believe I found that it wouldn't allow me to also pass in a report variable.  If you know of a way, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can do this.

I tested this by adding a variable `TestVariable` to a report, then adding the following custom code:

```
Function TestVariableFunctionality(var as Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable) As String
    Return var.Value
End Function
```

I called the function from a textbox like so:

`=Code.TestVariableFunctionality(Variables!TestVariable)`

This outputs the variable's value in the textbox as a string.

You must declare the full namespace as `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable`, because `Variable` alone is not defined. See below for more info.

[Accessing variable in SSRS function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013504/accessing-variable-in-ssrs-function)

[From an MSDN blog:](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2012/02/03/modifying-report-variables-in-reporting-service-2008-r2/)

> Assume that you've created a report variable named "Reportvariable1".
>
> All you need is a piece of custom code.
>
> Public Function SetVariableValue(val as Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable)
>
> val.Value = val.Value + 2
>
> End Function
>
> As simple as that. All i'm doing in the function is, take the report variable reference, add 2 to the existing value. That's it.
>
> How you can call this function from your report item?
>
> =Code.SetVariableValue(Variables!Reportvariable1)
>
> This will do the magic. Also note that in the above expression i'm just passing the variable reference and not its value.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Saving this for the future!  Would have never figured this out.

Comment: Happy to help @PabloCruise! Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: McGlothin, I'll gladly do so.  However 30+ years in IT and I can't figure how to accept your answer. Is there a button?  Probably right in front of my nose.

Comment: There should be a check mark next to the vote arrows. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work