# SSRS How to feed a certain value of a Dataset Field to a Variable in a Custom Code

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have  a report which contains conditional formatting. The colour value is feeding through Variables in a Custom Code on the report as below, `Dim vRed as String ="#FF0000" Dim vGreen as String ="#008000"` and the coding continues..

Now the problem is, we have many reports and if we wanted to change the colour we have to change each report. Therefore, we created a Config Table with two columns. One for ColourName and another for ColourCode.

Now I wanted to feed "red" ColourCode to `vRed` in the Custom Code. Can someone help me how to do this please.

Comment: Just to clarify trying to feed Field value (ColourCode) on a Dataset to a variable in the Function. If that makes sense.

Comment: Why not just join to your config table and use the ColourCode field as the colour expression, eg, if you wanted to set the `backcolor` property you would just set it to `=Fields!ClourCode.Value`

Comment: Nope the issue is there is a complicated function which i don't want to touch. Somehow I wanted to feed the ColourCode value to the Variable in the function.

Comment: just create a dataset that contains the colour values and then pass them to your function as parameters

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do. But my VB is not good.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set a variable, you can create a function with the variable and value to set it.

```
Public Function SetVariableValue(varName as Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable, varValue as String)

varName.Value = varValue 

End Function
```

Then you need to call it like

```
=CODE.SetVariableValue(Variables!CCColors.Value, FIRST(Fields!Color.Value, "Dataset1"))
```

See [SSRS reference report variable from report function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644956/ssrs-reference-report-variable-from-report-function)

Comment: Useful, I've never used this method. I've not needed to, but useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a bit of code like this.

```
Public Function myFunction (someParameter AS Integer, someOtherParameter as String) AS String

Dim vRed as String = "#FF0000"
Dim vGreen as String = "#008000"
Dim vBlue as String = "#0000FF"

' some code here 

End Function
```

And you call your code with something like

```
=Code.myFunction(Fields!SomeInt.Value, Fields!SomeText.Value)
```

You will need to create a dataset called `dsColours` containing your colour values, as it's a very small table, I would pivot this to make it easier to reference in the report.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT ColourCode FROM myConfigTable WHERE ColourName = 'Red') AS Red,
    (SELECT ColourCode FROM myConfigTable WHERE ColourName = 'Green') AS Green,
    (SELECT ColourCode FROM myConfigTable WHERE ColourName = 'Blue') AS Blue
    FROM myConfigTable
```

Now change your function to look like this.

```
Public Function myFunction (someParameter AS Integer, someOtherParameter as String, vRed as String, vGreen as String, vBlue as String) AS String

' some code here 

End Function
```

and call your new function like this

```
=Code.myFunction(Fields!SomeInt.Value, Fields!SomeText.Value,
                 FIRST(Fields!vRed.Value, "dsColours"),
                 FIRST(Fields!vGreen.Value, "dsColours"),
                 FIRST(Fields!vBlue.Value, "dsColours")
                 )
```